# Eclipse Plugin's plugin.xml file doesn't add a menu or export wizard specified in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add a export action to the Eclipse File > Export dialog. I've tried adding it through plugin.xml **(see below update about dropins vs plugins folder)** and while it works in a Mars 2 (Eclipse Platform / RCP version 4.5.2) instance it does not work with version 4.6.2 where I'm intending to use the jar. Previously the plugin.xml did not work also for a menu item, however I was able to do that programmatically (but seemingly not add an export wizard programmatically).

**Update 2: It seems it may have to do with the eclipse's configuration config.ini file or Equinox Transforms** (see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms). I think it may be the later because the plugins run and you can add ui elements later (like the aforementioned menu) with programming, but not with the plugin.xml. Also the config.ini makes reference to the Equinox Transforms class.

**Update 1: The plugin.xml not running seems to be related to something to do with the dropins folder.**

1. Foo.jar provides some exports and was provided by the vendor through a P2 update site I believe and exists in a plugins folder.
2. When I rename Foo.jar to Foo.jar.old and re run the app (with -clean) the exports are removed **(Good)**
3. When I name it back to Foo.jar in the plugins folder it re adds the exports on startup **(Good)**
4. When I move Foo.jar to the dropins folder the plugin DOES LOAD (it's listed in Help > Installation Details > Plugins), **however the export options specified in the plugin.xml are not populated.** **(Bad)**

Is there a difference between the eclipse dropins folder and the eclipse plugins folder of a P2 update site?

Comment: How are you installing into 4.6? If done properly, plugin.xml should absolutely still work.

Comment: Yes I went to the Help > Installation Details > Eclipse RCP is 4.6.2 ... It seems this could be related to plugins vs dropins folder. I'm putting the jars in the dropins folder. I tested with a jar in the plugins folder (not mine) that did work and copied it to dropins folder, it loaded but the export options weren't added.

Comment: Try specifying the `-clean` option when starting Eclipse to make sure it rebuilds the caches. 'Export > Deployable plugins and fragments' is the preferred way of building a plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 I did add -clean each time I ran the program. I also exported the plugin the way you mentioned. Foo.jar still exhibited the above issues with -clean and the plugin still didn't load the plugin.xml with that export.

Comment: @greg-449 I continued to confirm this by running a couple of other tests and it definitely doesn't seem to be directly related with -clean. E.g if I run -clean it does / doesn't work (see the below 'answer') when it shouldn't / should.

Comment: @nitind It does seem the plugin.xml may be loaded and the issue may be a result of the UI being 'restricted' instead, preventing menus / export addition being modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have since confirmed it was a Equinox Transform** in use (it shows up in the plugin list). Upon searching for jar files mentioning transform one had the xlst files in the jar and unzipping them, editing them, rezipping them to a jar file and replacing the original fixed the problem (I did have to run `eclipse.exe -clean` otherwise it did cache the old one and seem not to work).

Also of note look at the config.ini it should make reference to Equinox Transforms.